# Efficient conversion between vector<shared_ptr<T>> and vector<shared_ptr<const T>>

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a class:

```
class X {
  vector<shared_ptr<T>> v_;

 public:
  vector<shared_ptr<const T>> getTs() { return v_; }
};
```

It has a `vector` of `shared_ptr` of type `T`.  For some reason, it needs to expose a method to return this vector.  However, I don't want the content of the vector to be modified, neither are the objects being pointed to.  So I need to return a `vector` of `shared_ptr<const T>`.

My question is, is there any efficient way to achieve this?  If I simply return it, it works, but it needs to reconstruct a vector, which is kind of expensive.

Thanks.

Comment: Is it actually *too* expensive? Have you measured?

Comment: It should be, compared to `const vector<shared_ptr<T>>& getTs() { return v_; }`.  I want to achieve the speed of this form, as well as safety of the other form.

Comment: Wouldn't a non-copying conversion be, at its core, non-`const`-safe? Imagine that the class's client called `getTs().push_back(shared_ptr_to_truly_const_object)`; then your class could modify `truly_const_object` via `v_`. (This is the same reason that there's no implicit conversion from `T**` to `const T**`.)

Comment: Kerrek SB, I haven't measured it, but intuitively, if I call the function a lot, and the vector is sufficiently large.  It will be very expensive.

Comment: @icando : That in no way means it's actually a bottleneck in your code. ;-]

Comment: @ildjarn: I feel like you're only making half a point here. If I saw code that returned `vector<T>` in a hundred places where `const vector<T> &` would serve the purpose, I'd want to fix it, even if it *wasn't* a bottleneck. It's more important to fix bottlenecks than to fix random bits of inefficiencies, but I think it's very reasonable to ask, "I have what looks like a random bit of inefficiency; is there some way to fix it? Am I missing something simple?" Especially if one of your goals is, as it should be, to improve as a programmer.

Comment: @ruakh : The point is that, here, a `vector<T> const&` will _not_ serve the purpose, because he has a `vector<shared_ptr<T>>` and wants to return a `vector<shared_ptr<T const>>`. I agree with your point in general, but that simply isn't an option here.

Comment: @ildjarn: It's true that a `vector<T> const&` will not serve the purpose, but it's not true that you made that point. It's obvious to *you* that there's no simple-and-clearly-better way to do this while avoiding the copy (such that it's *only* worth worrying about if it's a bottleneck), but that's not *a priori* obvious to everyone. If the answer to the OP's question had been something like, "Yeah, RTFM, that's exactly what `std::vector.get_convenient_const_view()` is for", no one would have felt the need to ask if this is a bottleneck . . .

Comment: @ruakh : I also left a comment rather than an answer. I don't think there's any obligation on my part to be that thorough in a comment. ;-]

Comment: @ildjarn: O.K., fair enough. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can not do that directly - but you can define "views" on your container that let you do something very similar, if you want to make sure that your pointees are const:

```
boost::any_range<
  std::shared_ptr<const int>,
  boost::random_access_traversal_tag,
  std::shared_ptr<const int>,
  std::ptrdiff_t
> foo(std::vector<std::shared_ptr<int>>& v)
{
  return v;
}
```

A simple transform iterator adapter / transformed range might do the trick as well, I just used this to illustrate the point.

Comment: Both KitsuneYMG's answer and this one fit my need.

Comment: @icando : Note that if you use this approach, since your underlying container is a `std::vector<>`, you can use `boost::random_access_traversal_tag` to allow random-access traversal over your view instead of limiting it to forward-only traversal.

Comment: Yet another part of boost I need to go investigate. I really wish our hands weren't tied to C89 for on-the-job development. Curse you Mathworks!

Answer (score 2):

Why not return it as a set of `iterator`s?

```
class X {
  vector<shared_ptr<T>> v_;
  class const_iterator : std::iterator< std::bidirectional_iterator_tag, T >
  {
    vector<shared_ptr<T>>::iterator it;
    const_iterator( vector<shared_ptr<T>>::iterator& v ) :it (v) { }
    const T& operator*() { return const_cast<const T>( **it ); }
    //forward all methods
  }

   public:
  const_iterator ts_begin() { return const_iterator(v_.begin()); }
  const_iterator ts_end() { return const_iterator(v_.end()); }
};
```

or something similar? That gives you full control over the type and how it's accessed. Plus you can later change the type w/o changing the api.

Answer (score 1):

You are returning by value, so the cost is the same whether you return a copy of the original, vector or a copy of a vector of `shared_ptr<T const>`: One memory allocation and N atomic increments (approx.).

If what you want to avoid is the creation of the returned vector (i.e. return by value), then it is impossible as different template instantiations are unrelated types no matter how related the arguments to the template are.

Comment: Maybe I didn't phrase the question well enough, sorry for my bad English.  I was trying to achieve something like `const vector<shared_ptr<const T>>& getTs() { return v_; }`.  However, this won't work because C++ don't think shared_ptr<const T> and shared_ptr<T> the same type.

Comment: Re: first paragraph: I'm pretty sure that the OP understands that. Hence his/her remark, "If I simply return it, it works, but it needs to reconstruct a vector, which is kind of expensive." (I assume that by "simply return it" (s)he means "return it by value".)

Comment: @icando: Yes, that is the second paragraph... `shared_ptr<T>` and `shared_ptr<T const>` are completely unrelated types, so that is impossible.